# Collection view - Bubble border and fill color changes to different color

Tags: ios, swift

I am using collection view and we have added bubble to the cell.
Also, bubble has the different fill color and border color.

Please find attachment for details.

[image]

but when we scroll collection view that time bubble color sometime changed to different and again restored to correct color.

Here's my code:

```
          func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {   

// INIT CELLS INSIDE COLLECTION VIEW

if(collectionView == customContentCollectionView){

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: contentCellId, for: indexPath) as! MyContentCell

    setupContentCellComponents(cell: cell)

    // Configure the cell
    cell.horizontalLine.backgroundColor = Color.lightBlue

    var labelColour = UIColor()
    // If we found record
    if(self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].interactions != ""){         //  GENERATING CUSTOM BUBBLE COLOR AS PER INTERACTIONS
        let (bubbleBorder, bubbleFill, labelColor, inspectorNav) = getBubbleColor(controlType: controlParam, count: Int(self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].interactions)!, selected: false)

        cell.shapeLayer.strokeColor = bubbleBorder.cgColor
        cell.shapeLayer.fillColor = bubbleFill.cgColor
        cell.gradient.colors = [bubbleFill.cgColor, bubbleFill.cgColor]
        labelColour = labelColor
    }

    cell.labelCount.font =  UIFont(name: cellFontName, size: cellFontSize)
    cell.labelCount.text = self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].interactions
    if (self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].umid != ""){
        cell.tag = Int(self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].umid)!
        cell.labelCount.tag = Int(self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].umid)!
        cell.labelCount.textColor = labelColour
    }
    else  (self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].umid == ""){           //  REMOVING BUBBLE IF NO CONTENT
        cell.shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()//remove from superview
    }

}
```

Here's scrolling logic :

```
 func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
// selectedSection is the value where you have tapped
if(selectedSection != -1){
        for i in 0...numberOfItemsInSection{                                                      //  CODE TO MAINTAIN ROW HIGHLIGHT POST SCROLL
            let newIndices = IndexPath(row: i, section: selectedSection)
            for visibleIndices in customContentCollectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems{
                if(newIndices == visibleIndices){
                    print("NEW INDICES: \(newIndices)")
                    if(newIndices.section == selectedSection){
                        selectedRowCells.append(customContentCollectionView.cellForItem(at: newIndices)!)
                    }
    // horizontal line for selected bubble
    let singleCell : MyContentCell = customContentCollectionView.cellForItem(at: newIndices)! as! MyContentCell
                        singleCell.horizontalLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

                        if(previouslySelectedIndex != nil && visibleIndices == previouslySelectedIndex){
                            changeBubbleColor(index: previouslySelectedIndex, selected: true)
                            break
                        }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,
Here if cell satisfies the condition then properties are set but if the condition is not satisfied at that time cell takes previous properties set in the conditon so you also need to set the properties in else condition also

so try by setting properties as suggested with comment in code below

I hope you will get your solution

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        //  INIT CELLS INSIDE COLLECTION VIEW

        if(collectionView == customContentCollectionView){

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: contentCellId, for: indexPath) as! MyContentCell

            setupContentCellComponents(cell: cell)

            // Configure the cell
            cell.horizontalLine.backgroundColor = Color.lightBlue

            var labelColour = UIColor()
            // If we found record
            if(self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].interactions != "")
            {         //  GENERATING CUSTOM BUBBLE COLOR AS PER INTERACTIONS
                let (bubbleBorder, bubbleFill, labelColor, inspectorNav) = getBubbleColor(controlType: controlParam, count: Int(self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].interactions)!, selected: false)

                cell.shapeLayer.strokeColor = bubbleBorder.cgColor
                cell.shapeLayer.fillColor = bubbleFill.cgColor
                cell.gradient.colors = [bubbleFill.cgColor, bubbleFill.cgColor]
                labelColour = labelColor
            }
            else
            {
                //set default cell.shapeLayer.strokeColor
                //set default cell.shapeLayer.fillColor
                //set default cell.gradient.colors
                //set default labelColour
            }

            cell.labelCount.font =  UIFont(name: cellFontName, size: cellFontSize)
            cell.labelCount.text = self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].interactions
            if (self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].umid != "")
            {
                cell.tag = Int(self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].umid)!
                cell.labelCount.tag = Int(self.bubbleArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.item].umid)!
                cell.labelCount.textColor = labelColour
            }
            else
            {
                //Set default cell.tag
                //Set default cell.labelCount.tag
                //Set default cell.labelCount.textColor

            }

        }
```

Comment: Tried, but not working. Also, If umid or interaction is empty that means we are not setting that bubble. I have edited the question to include the code, please check.